# How to replace string satisfying a complex condition?

Tags: php

I have two cases:

- **case1:** `string = "<ul class='list-group'>"`
- **case2:** `string = "<ul>"`

Now I want to replace `<ul>` with `<ul class='list-group'>` but If I do so.  `<ul class='list-group'>` is also changed as follows:

```
<ul class='list-group' class='list-group'>
```

I can I change  which does not have `list-group` class?

Comment: If you're calling `str_replace()` and you're just replacing `"<ul>"` it shouldn't have any effect on case 1. Post your code.

Comment: Just replace the string `<ul>` with `<ul class='list-group'>` .

Comment: It sounds like you may be replacing `<ul` rather than `<ul>`. Or maybe you're using a regular expression when you don't need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this:

```
$string = '<ul>';
echo str_replace('<ul>','<ul class="list-group">',$string);
```